# working directory for cygwin using it in c#

Tags: c#, bash, cygwin

I have a problem, I start cygwin commands with c#, what is working fine. The Problem is to set the working directory.

```
   pathANDcommand = C:\cygwin\bin\ls.exe";
   arg = " -lisa";

   System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.FileName = pathANDcommand;
        startInfo.Arguments = arg;
        output.Enqueue(arg + "\n" + "\n");
        startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"\cygdrive\c\Users\jhb\Source\Repos\myprogramm";
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
```

If I set startInfo.WorkingDirectory to a windows path the program will run, but the command does not run in the path I set.

Comment: I'll just leave this here... [BASH on Windows](http://www.theverge.com/2016/3/30/11331014/microsoft-windows-linux-ubuntu-bash). Not that it helps you today.

Comment: Are you sure it is `myprogramm`? Note the two `m`.

Comment: no it isnt myprogamm, because it has another name ;) And I need a solution which is not in the future ...

Comment: ps:  ls is just a example. I would use rsync, but its to complicated for the example.